# Are there any Rails plugins that allow for Excel-like functionality in the views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am looking for a way to allow web users to view tabular information in a view, and interact with the data in a similar way. In other words:

Tab through cells
Highlight multiple cells
Fill multiple cells simultaneously

Does such a plugin exist? I have not been able to locate one via search engines.

Comment: this look like something for a js ui framework. like that maybe? http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/restful/restful.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe activescaffold is what you want? http://activescaffold.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check out something like Google's charting API, it includes an [interactive table](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/table.html#Example) which can be sorted by headers etc. It doesn't look like it does editing, but I'm not sure if that's a requirement for you or not. If you need an editable table, I guess you'd be looking for a specialised wysiwyg editor in javascript for that.